# Why did an update to gnome-terminal break my system-colours and how do I fix it?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-terminal

I am on arch-linux and just upgraded to the latest version of `gnome-terminal`. I used to have both the terminal colour and theme set by `gnome-tweak-tool` having `Global Dark Theme` turned on. Does anyone know how to change this back without downgrading my terminal. You can see here what the terminal now looks like, and a window that looks correct. [image: example showing the problem]

I downgraded my terminal to the last one that did not do this, so the problem is somewhere between: gnome-terminal 3.12.0-1 and 3.10.2-1 (3.10.2-1 is the working one, these are from the arch package manager).

Comment: Have added a bugreport to archlinux [here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/40081?string=gnome-terminal&project=1&search_name=&type%5B0%5D=&sev%5B0%5D=&pri%5B0%5D=&due%5B0%5D=&reported%5B0%5D=&cat%5B0%5D=&status%5B0%5D=open&percent%5B0%5D=&opened=&dev=&closed=&duedatefrom=&duedateto=&changedfrom=&changedto=&openedfrom=&openedto=&closedfrom=&closedto=) as per instructions [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/ReportingBugs) hopefully it gets bounced upstream.

Comment: gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings dark-theme true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set gnome-terminal to use dark theme in the preferences of it?

Comment: This is the solution, in previous versions the option was set through `Profile Preferences` with `use system colour theme` (under colours) I neglected to check the `Preferences` where they had created a new option called `use dark theme variant` which overrides the `use system colour theme`

Comment: @Regulus I suggest you edit your answer to include a little more detail (like the stuff that is currently in Mike's comment about how they moved the setting).